# How do you "find a new member for the Tsnemo crew" (Recruiter achievement)?

Tags: achievements, across-the-obelisk

The rarest achievement in the game is

```
Recruiter
Find a new member for the Tsnemo crew
```

How do I unlock this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a tadpole in someone's eye as Nezglekt, then visit Tsnemo.

---

There are three people who can be eye-tadpoled, all in Act I.

[image: Act I]

1. If this book is *blue*, you can do the quest to get Betty, the sheep pet, and tadpole someone at the end.
2. If this book is *not green* you can do a quest to save the farmer's son, and tadpole him at the start.
3. If all else fails, you can tadpole the werewolf merchant.

After this, simply go to Act IV and visit Tsnemo.

[image: Act IV]

This was one of the easier achievements to find, so I'm confused why it's so rare. Maybe no one picks Nezglekt because he's weak early on (even though he's by far the strongest late-game healer)?